# Grouping same values of a df column into a single variable

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I merged two dfs from data scraped online;

```
merge_data = pd.merge(WikiData,SPData, on='Symbol')
merge_data.set_index('Symbol',inplace=True)
merge_data.head()
```

and get the following df:

```
        Sector      Sub-industry    Company     Weight
Symbol              
MMM    Industrials  Conglomerates   MCompany    0.602676
ABT    Health Care  Equipment       Abbott Lab  0.401900
ABBV   Health Care  Pharmaceuticals AbbVie Inc  0.550174
ACN    Info Tech    Consulting      Accenture   0.370650
ATVI   Info Tech    Entertainment   Activision  0.192788
```

How can I group same values of the 'Sector' column together? For example, I want all stocks that are in the "Health Care" sector to be = to a 'XLV' variable, and all stocks in "Info Tech" = 'XLK'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new column and apply a dictionary that has a key value for each new label

```
labels = { 'Health Care': 'XLV', 'Info Tech': 'XLK' }

merge_data['new_label'] = merge_data['Sector'].apply(lambda sector: labels[sector])
```

Comment: i get NameError: global name 'sector' is not defined

Comment: KeyError: u'Industrials'

Comment: You have to define in the labels dictionary. You only provided two examples this should work.